# Simplifying gather() with pivot_longer() using multiple ID columns and value columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm working to get a better handle on `pivot_longer`, coming from a `gather` user. From the source documents it seems like I should be able to do the following in a single command using name_pattern or `names_sep` but I've been unable to find a working solution.

Data

```
id1 <- c("person1","person2","person3")
id2 <- c("1001","1002","1003")
id3 <- c("2001","2002", "2003")
value_1 <- c(10,50,100)
value_2 <- c(20,200, 2000)
status_1 <- c("OK","BAD","GOOD")
status_2 <- c("AWFUL","EXCELLENT","AVERAGE")

df <- data.frame(id1,id2,id3,value_1,value_2,status_1,status_2)
```

Expected output:

```
      id1  id2  id3 gradeLevel    status value
1 person1 1001 2001          1        OK    10
2 person1 1001 2001          2     AWFUL    20
3 person2 1002 2002          1       BAD    50
4 person2 1002 2002          2 EXCELLENT   200
5 person3 1003 2003          1      GOOD   100
6 person3 1003 2003          2   AVERAGE  2000
```

I can achieve this with a `gather` statement and a few extra lines:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value,-id1, -id2,-id3) %>% 
  separate(key, c('cat', 'gradeLevel'),sep ="_") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  spread(cat,value)
```

Is there a way to simplify this with `pivot_longer`? I think names_pattern is promising but I struggle with regex. Most of my attempts are attempting to combine different types of columns (double & factor)

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = value_1:status_2, names_to = c('col', '.value'), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following solution. In this case we create 2 capture groups. What `.value` does here actually is to define for `pivot_longer` the part of the name that contains the name of the value we are trying to measure. Here the left side of the underscore are values `value` and `status`. The right side of the underscore which is in fact the result of our second capturing group defines the `id`. And it should be noted that the length of `names_to` argument should be the same as the number of capturing groups in `names_pattern` or possibly `names_sep`.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(id1, id2, id3), names_to = c(".value", "gradelevel"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)_(\\d+)")

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  id1     id2   id3   gradelevel value status   
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    
1 person1 1001  2001  1             10 OK       
2 person1 1001  2001  2             20 AWFUL    
3 person2 1002  2002  1             50 BAD      
4 person2 1002  2002  2            200 EXCELLENT
5 person3 1003  2003  1            100 GOOD     
6 person3 1003  2003  2           2000 AVERAGE
```

Comment: Very helpful. To check my understanding I could substitute "(.+)_(.+)" to allow lookup of any word or digit on both sides of the underscore, correct?

Comment: Yes that would yield the same result in this case. This (.*)_(.*)  also works. But there are very more complicated cases in which you need to define your capturing groups specifically for numbers of words or any other character.

Comment: That makes sense, appreciate it.